# What similarity measure does More Like This (mlt) score words with in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I set a field's [similarity function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/index-modules-similarity.html) to be something like BM25, does [More Like This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) use that similarity score to pick top words for it's disjunctive boolean search (or is the default tf-idf used, as suggested by the docs: `[MLT] selects the top K terms with highest tf-idf to form a disjunctive query of these terms.`)? And separately, does the returned order/score reflect the default tf-idf similarity or the one that I set?

Comment: After experimenting with changing a field's similarity metric, I do get different results, so MLT isn't entirely resting on the default Lucene scoring, but it would be nice to know answers to the specific questions above.